# Error: cannot allocate vector of size 61.6 Gb In addition: Warning messages: 1: Reached total allocation of 8191Mb:

Tags: r, ff

I get this error when i tried to use the data which has 4 datetime columns. I tried using ff package but it again leads to the errors which changes the datatype ofthe dependent variable in my linear regression model.
Please let me know how to use the ff package too.

Comment: This error can simply be hat you need more memory for what you are trying to do, but this can be the result of  a non-sensible line of code. So can you show what code gives the error, and also add the results from `str(yourdataframe)` to your question please.

Comment: Hi, Got rid of the error by using Sparklyr. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: do you have any solution for this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46363862/regression-method-to-be-adopted-for-continuous-dependent-variable-with-categoric

Comment: model_formula1 <- formula(ProcessDuration ~ ProcessGroup 
                         + ProcessSourceSystem
                         + SUBProcessPriority + SubStartTime + SubEndTime + ProcessStatus)
mymodelDeci <- ml_decision_tree(edw_train_tbl,model_formula1),  i used this code with the help of sparklyr, here i get a different error when i add the date attributes(SubStartTime,SubEndTime ). Any idea how to handle date variables so that it can be used as independent variables?